# Is it thread safe to create a new Mutex in Go?

Tags: go, struct, concurrency, mutex

I have a struct in Go which contains a mutex, and I want to ensure that that mutex is never `nil`. To that end, I have implemented a `GetMutex()` function, which checks if the mutex is nil, and if it is, then assigns it a value.

My question is: is the following code thread safe? If not, what would be an idiomatic way to ensure that `mux` is always initialized? The only thing I can think of is to have a global mutex in this package which is used within my `GetMutex()` function, but perhaps there is a different approach.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

type Counter struct {
    mux *sync.Mutex
    counter int
}

// Is this thread safe?
func (c *Counter) GetMux() *sync.Mutex {
    if c.mux == nil {
        c.mux = &sync.Mutex{}
    }
    return c.mux
}

func (c *Counter) Inc() {
    c.GetMux().Lock()
    c.counter++
    c.GetMux().Unlock()
}

func main() {
    c := &Counter{}
    c.Inc()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not safe if `Counter.GetMux()` is called from multiple goroutines concurrently: `GetMux()` both reads and writes the `Counter.mux` field.

The general way is to use a "constructor" like function that takes care of the initialization, like this:

```
func NewCounter() *Counter {
    return &Counter{
        mux: &sync.Mutex{},
    }
}
```

And of course always create counters with this `NewCounter()`.

Another–limited–way would be to use a non-pointer mutex value:

```
type Counter struct {
    mux     sync.Mutex
    counter int
}
```

So when you have a `Counter` struct value, it–by design–includes a mutex. But if you do this, then `Counter` should always be used as a pointer, and `Counter` struct values must not be copied (else the mutex field would also be copied, but as package doc of [`sync`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) states: *"Values containing the types defined in this package should not be copied."*).

The obvious advantage of this is that the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of `Counter` is a valid and ready counter (something you should aim for with your custom types), and no constructor function is needed.